# Two stage operation amplifier using MOSFET: How to increase the cut off frequency

Tags: operational-amplifier, mosfet, electronic-load, gain-bandwidth-product

[image]so I'm trying to design a two stage MOSFET op amp and I'm required to get a gain bandwidth of more than 260Ghz. I'm biasing the first stage with Vb1 around 2.1 V, 1.9 for 2 and 2V for Vb3. With Vdd =3.5V I choose them because they biased all the M in sat. Anyway, I'm limited to an overall current in the circuit that around 5mA. Anyway, I'm getting an almost of 25 V/V gain at the first stage and almost 5 at the second. The problem is the cut off frequency is about 100Mhz. As far as I know, the fcut is gm/ Cgs in this case. However, I'm not sure which Cgs to use in the circuit, is it the input Cgs the one corresponds to M1 is that true?

I also tried to increase the W/L ratio of M1 to increase the gm hence to increase the gain, but the doesn't seem to change the GBW much. Is there are another way to increase the GBW ? Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Gain Bandwidth is not the same as cutoff frequency (unless you meant gain@3dbXfreq@3db). Can find GBW when gain curve crosses 0dB, it is that bandwidth with gain 1, which is much greater than cutoff (freq@3dB). It is usually a function of gain (gm_in * Ro) and dominant pole (often 1/Ro * CLoad). To maximize, you can maximize gm (as you did) and minimize dominant pole capacitances. 260GHz seems extremely high for GBW in cmos, but you show no specifics about devices, models, parasitics, etc. Having no external CL, might make it acheivable.

Comment: *The problem is the cut off frequency is about 100Mhz* It is not if you make the gain 2600. In general bandwidth and gain can traded against eachother. Hints: 1) draw the **small signal equivalent circuit**. 2) From that determine dominant pole(s) and zero(s). 3) Worry about DC biasing later. You're using a lot of "as far as I know" and "not sure" that makes me wonder what level of education you get before such an assignment. In my case that was a course over multiple weeks with homework etc. And that was **after** I already had my master in EE.